# i want to dynamically add layout to android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am developing simple score sheet app screen in which there are four edittext and one textview , now what i want is once the values are entered in this the score is calculated and diplayed in textviews under and if score is less than 100 than new layout containing all these widgets is automatically added my code for this is

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true"
  android:scrollbars="none" 
  androidLid="@+id/main">

 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/meld1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/meld2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/meld1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/meld1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="108dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EditText02"
        android:text="Dealer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText05"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/meld2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText05"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  and the layout to be added is

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/add"
>
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/meld1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/meld1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/meld1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/meld1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

So,here what i want to do is to add add layout under scrollview layout on change of text in all four edittexts my code to add layout is

```
     LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
     View hiddenInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, scrollview01,    false);
            myLayout.addView(hiddenInfo);
```

But i am unable to add this layout under scroll view and after adding this layout i want to add text watcher on every edittext and update the text view of that layout only for example

```
et.addTextWatcher{
//do something
  tv.settext(something);
  }
```

now on based of change in its value i want to update the value of textviews in this added layout
Any hint or solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast your "ScrollView" as a LinearLayout and add children. ScrollViews by definintion can only have 1 child element. Please try referencing your LinearLayout child view and adding views to that.

Something like

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none" 
android:id="@+id/main">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/main_root"
>

//etc...
```

Then add the new view to the linear layout

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_root);
//context references your activity context.
View hiddenInfo = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.add, myLayout, true);
```

See "inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)" from the [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) Documentation

Comment: then after that how can i detect click on the recently added ant its previous widgets

Comment: you should be able to add the onClickListener to any object just like normal, just use something like 

     EditText et1 = (EditText)hiddenInfo.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Comment: i got you i can have listener on recently added layout widget. now if i want to particularly have listener on say widgets of 2n or 3rd added layout ,in general say some particular layout then how can i acheive that thats what my ques is.